# Can a Baofeng UV-5R Display Both Name and Frequency Simultaneously?

Tags: baofeng, uv-5r

The Baofeng UV-5R style radios have a 2 line display that can display the Name, Frequency, OR Number of the selected memory location for each of 2 memory locations.

Is it possible to display the Name AND Frequency using both lines for just one memory location?

Comment: Wish they had a "hot key" to flip between Name and Frequency for a channel. Like the power toggle is hot keyed to short press of lock button. That would be perfect. But it is a royal PitA to have to go into the menu every time and toggle the A or B display...sigh.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you cannot display "Name & Frequency" if the unit is in "Channel Mode".

what you could do is program (part of) the frequency in the "Name field" of the channel. This way it helps you, like a hint, of what frequency the channel is set to.

Obviously it will get more complicated if you have different RX and TX frequencies programmed in the Channel, you need to be very creative with the name you will give it. (if not using standard offsets that is, as standard offsets will display as a little `+` or `-` in the display)

The second line of the display is really for A/B of your VFO.

Comment: The A/B also works in "Channel Mode".  For example, I have "A" set for the channel of one local repeater and "B" set for another.  That way I can easily switch between them using the A/B button.

Comment: Yes, I never said the two line A/B wouldn't work in channel mode.

Comment: I was just trying to clarify your use of the phrase "really for" in case anyone found it confusing.

Comment: This is not true, you can set the receiver to display the set frequency instead of the name alias while you are in channel mode.

Comment: @SandPiper What isn't true?  No one ever said you couldn't.  It was stated in the OP that this can be done.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, kind of. You can program the A and B settings separately. Set channel A to display name, and set B to display frequency. Also, set the receiver to only listen to the monitored channel to ensure you won't run into problems.

Then, in channel mode, use your programmed station (ex station 12) on both A and B simultaneously. A will show your channel name alias, and B will show the frequency. It is a workaround, but it will give you what you're looking for.

Comment: This is exactly what I do on my UV-B5s and it works really well.

Answer (score 1):

A new Menu 24 on the BTECH UV5X3 Triband radio is "SYNC" and is ON or OFF.  This is a great addition. You can program a Marine channel 16 and see "CH 16" in one display and "156.80" in the other display. For Amateur repeaters, it's nice to know the repeater callsign in one display and the actual Frequency in the other.

The only downside is dual monitoring.

If ON, and you have FREQ in the A display, and CHAN in the B display, changing either channel, either UP DOWN or by typing in a channel number, you will see the NAME in one VFO and the Frequency in the other display.

On the UV5 models, there is no such capability.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about that model, but the btech (appears to be another name for the same hardware) can sync the name and frequency. It was /is an option, if I had my radio I could look it up. It might be only in the newer radios/firmware.

Comment: @SDsolar It displays the name too, but it is either/or.  I would like to be able to use the two lines of the display to display both.

Comment: @wag Mine is actually a BF-F9 V2+ with Gen 3 firmware, so if it is possible this one should do it.  If you get a chance and could let me know the option, I'd really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

@ W6FCC "On the UV5 models, there is no such capability." (Que dramatic music)

Actually, all you have to do when the UV5* is configured as stated, is press A/B and the channel number to be decoded. Voilà! A frequency! I do it all the time and saved 40+ $$$ towards my bar tab.